# Mongoose encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption, mongoose

How to encrypt the sub docs excluding specific fields in the sub docs?

I am trying to implement encryption on below schema using the [mongoose-encryption plugin](https://github.com/cinch-financial/mongoose-encryption). My parent schema i.e. "parentSchema" gets encrypted, but not the child schema. I need to encrypt the "childSchema" and "childinformationSchema". What i am missing here?

```
var childinformationSchema = new Schema({
    otherwitnes: String,
    reportedemployOther: String,
    status: String,
    updateddate: Date,
    updatedby: String
});

childinformationSchema.plugin(encrypt, {
    key: encryptionKey,
    exclude: ['status', 'updateddate', 'updatedby']
});

var childSchema = new Schema({
    childdata: {
        childinformation: [childinformationSchema]
    }
});

childSchema.plugin(encrypt.encryptedChildren, {
    key: encryptionKey
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    practicename: String,
    createddate: Date,
    createdby: String,
    updateddate: Date,
    updatedby: String,
    patientrecordno: String,
    state: String,
    child: [childSchema]
});

 parentSchema.plugin(
    encrypt.encryptedChildren,
    { 
        key: encryptionKey,
        exclude: ['createddate', 'createdby', 'updateddate', 'updatedby', 'state', 'patientrecordno', 'child'] 
    }
);
```

Comment: Any body here who can help me?

Comment: Be patient, someone with the required knowledge will eventually answer.

Comment: @joao maybe start a bounty? :)

Answer (score 1):

In your use case you have subdocuments of subdocuments. From some testing, Mongoose doesn't appear to fully support middleware on sub-subdocuments and so this plugin won't work without restructuring your schema some. This might be a good idea in general because MongoDB itself [doesn't have full support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) for nested nested arrays.

Would it work if you referenced the children at one of the levels instead of including them directly as a subdoc? For example:

```
childinformationSchema.plugin(encrypt, {
    encryptionKey: encryptionKey,
    authenticationKey: authenticationKey, // latest version adds authentication
    excludeFromEncryption: ['status', 'updateddate', 'updatedby']
});

var childSchema = new Schema({
    childinformation: [childinformationSchema]
});

// because childSchema itself has encrypted children
childSchema.plugin(encrypt.encryptedChildren);

var parentSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    child: [type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child']
});

parentSchema.plugin(encrypt, { 
    key: encryptionKey,
    excludeFromEncryption: ['createddate', 'createdby', 'updateddate', 'updatedby', 'state', 'patientrecordno', 'child']
});
```

Similarly, you could leave `childSchema` nested directly inside `parentSchema` and include `childinformationSchema` by reference instead.

More details on using subdocuments with mongoose-encryption in [the docs](https://github.com/cinch-financial/mongoose-encryption#encrypt-specific-fields-of-sub-docs)

Disclosure: I am the plugin author